# How can I download images stored at a particular path on firebase storage in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm getting the stream failed: network changed error when trying to download the images stored on firebase at the given path. MY network is fine and I've tried on multiple networks to be sure. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class MainScreenProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreenProfile({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainScreenProfile> createState() => _MainScreenProfileState();
}

class _MainScreenProfileState extends State<MainScreenProfile> {
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  List<DataRow> rows = [];

  Future<List<String>> getUrls() async {
    String path = 'userImages/lO6jIQTk6GbEI8mGnWJqhQnsZEJ2/';
    final ref = storage.ref(path);
    ListResult result;
    print(path);
    try {
      print('y');
      result = await ref.listAll();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error while listing all items: $e');
      return [];
    } // List all files in directory
    List<String> downloadUrls = [];

    for (var item in result.items) {
      String downloadUrl = await item.getDownloadURL();
      downloadUrls.add(downloadUrl);
    }

    return downloadUrls;
  }

  Map<String, String> fieldNames = {
    'About you - first name': 'First Name',
    'About you - last name': 'Last Name',
    'About you - gender': 'Gender',
    'About you 2 - dob': 'Date of Birth',
    'Please enter Email - email': 'Email',
    'Your profile - degree': 'Degree',
    'Your profile - university': 'University',
    'Your profile 2 - company': 'Company',
    'Your profile 2 - designation': 'Designation',
  };

  List<DataRow> _buildRowsFromDocumentData(Map<String, dynamic> docData) {
    List<DataRow> tempRows = [];
    List<String> desiredFields = [
      'About you - first name',
      'About you - last name',
      'About you - gender',
      'About you 2 - dob',
      'Please enter Email - email',
      'Your profile - degree',
      'Your profile - university',
      'Your profile 2 - company',
      'Your profile 2 - designation',
    ];

    docData.forEach((key, value) {
      if (desiredFields.contains(key)) {
        String displayName = fieldNames[key] ?? key;
        tempRows.add(DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text(displayName)),
          DataCell(Text(value.toString())),
        ]));
      }
    });
    return tempRows;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Settings',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontFamily: 'Exo2',
                fontSize: 32,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: getUrls(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.black,
              );
            } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
              return Center(child: Text('An error occurred!'));
            } else {
              // Fill a list with up to 6 items. If there are less than 6 images, the remaining items will be null.
              List<String?> images = List<String?>.filled(6, null);
              for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.length; i++) {
                images[i] = snapshot.data![i];
              }
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    deviceSize.width * 0.1, 0, deviceSize.width * 0.1, 0),
                child: GridView.count(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 15,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: List.generate(
                    6,
                    (index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          // _showPicker(context, index);
                        },
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 40,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                          child: images[index] != null
                              ? ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    images[index]!,
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                  ),
                                )
                              : Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  ),
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 100,
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.camera_enhance_rounded,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    size: 50,
                                  ),
                                ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: firestore
              .collection('users')
              .where('uid', isEqualTo: auth.currentUser!.uid)
              .get()
              .then((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.first),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.black,
              );
            } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
              return const Center(child: Text('An error occurred!'));
            } else {
              DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot;
              Map<String, dynamic>? docData =
                  docSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;

              if (docData == null) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text('No data found for this user!'),
                );
              }

              List<DataRow> builtRows = _buildRowsFromDocumentData(docData);

              return ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: deviceSize.height * 0.5,
                  minWidth: deviceSize.width,
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, // Ensures vertical scrolling
                  child: DataTable(
                    columnSpacing: 10, // Adjust to desired space
                    columns: [
                      const DataColumn(label: Text('Key')),
                      const DataColumn(label: Text('Value')),
                    ],
                    rows: builtRows,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The images are meant to download and be displayed in the circular cutouts.